# How to specify an operating System Family for Fargate task definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am using terraform to create a Fargate task definition but I am having some difficulty specifying the Runtime platform version. According to AWS's [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html)
the task definition `operatingSystemFamily` property does exist. Its default value is `LINUX`. I would like to change that to `Windows Server 2019 Core` as I would like to use Windows containers on Fargate.

Having said that, I am unable to find it on the Terraform's [aws_ecs_task_definition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition) resource documentation.

This is my task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "transform_service" {
  family                   = "${var.app_name}-transform-service-task"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                = 2 * 1024  #2 vCPU
  memory             = 16 * 1024 # 16GB
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.transform_service_task_execution_role.arn
  
  container_definitions = jsonencode([{
    name      = "transform-service-container-${var.environment}"
    image     = "${var.transform_service_repository_url}:latest"
    essential = true
    environment = [{
      "name" : "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", "value" : "Development"
    }]
    },

  ])
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. I can't find in the TF documentation or any examples. However you can find it for CloudFormation as the runtime platform. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-runtimeplatform.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not yet supported. There are GitHub **issues** for that already:

- [aws_ecs_task_definition missing runtimePlatform #21984](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/21984)
- [Add support for FARGATE Windows Containers and ARM based Containers](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/21706)

with a **PR ready**:

- [Add support for FARGATE Windows Containers and ARM based Containers](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/22016)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Marcin! That makes sense now. I searched the issues on the Terraform github page but could not find it

Comment: I have checked the `aws_ecs_service` terraform resource and it appears that it also does not have that property. I have opened an issue about that here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22033

Answer (score 1):

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "test" {
  family                   = "test"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = 1024
  memory                   = 2048
  container_definitions    = <<TASK_DEFINITION
[
  {
    "name": "iis",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis",
    "cpu": 1024,
    "memory": 2048,
    "essential": true
  }
]
TASK_DEFINITION

  runtime_platform {
    operating_system_family = "WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CORE"
    cpu_architecture        = "X86_64"
  }
}
```

Release notes here:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/22016

> Adds platform runtime properties and validation based on
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html
> runtime_platform {
> operating_system_family = "WINDOWS_SERVER_2019_CORE"
> cpu_architecture = "X86_64"   }